# one task previleged in asio io_service

Tags: boost-asio

I have `io_service` with one task (deadline_timer) that is fired every 1 sec.
Next, I want to create new thread by `thread t1(bind(&io_service::run, &ios));` for some other tasks.

How to be sure (if possible) that deadline_timer will not be interrupted? Or better, be sure that it has own thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee that an I/O object, such as a `deadline_timer`, has its own dedicated thread, one could use multiple `io_service` objects:

- an `io_service` for the timer processed by a single thread or group of threads
- an `io_service` for all other tasks and I/O objects processed by a different thread or different group of threads

Using multiple `io_service` objects can help prevent contention between event handling and dispatching.  For example, an `io_service` will not be impacted by a completion handler that is taking a long time to complete within a different `io_service`.  However, all threads are still subject to the OS scheduler, where interruptions may occur.

---

Below is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b04a15a72534458) using multiple `io_service` objects, where a `deadline_timer` is being processed by a dedicated thread:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void arm_timer(boost::asio::deadline_timer& timer)
{
  timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
  timer.async_wait([&timer]
    (const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
      std::cout << "timer: " << error.message() << std::endl;
      arm_timer(timer);
    });
}

int main()
{
  // Dedicate an io_service and thread to a single timer.
  boost::asio::io_service timer_io_service;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(timer_io_service);
  arm_timer(timer);
  std::thread timer_thread([&timer_io_service]() {
    timer_io_service.run();
  });

  // Use a different io_service for other tasks.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Post a tasks to stop the timer io_service.
  io_service.post([&timer_io_service]{
    timer_io_service.stop();
  });

  // Let timer run.
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
  io_service.run();

  timer_thread.join();  
}
```

Comment: Using `boost::asio::io_service` with a thread pool is a really easy way to write scaleable multithreaded applications, however when you require this level of control, one `io_service` per thread is the way to go.